# Centering div using translate leaves too much margin

Tags: html, css, text, responsive-design

I'm centering a DIV using translate

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

It does puts it in the middle, however with too much margin to each side. Meaning, that although it is in the middle, never does it go to the edges of the browser window, when the window is resized.

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80pt;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div>Look at me, I'm centered, with too much margin.</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LbQxLV

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: what is the exact issue?

Comment: Perhaps `white-space:nowrap`?

Comment: @Paulie_D the problem is demonstrated in the codepen.. the text is wrapped too early, there could have fitted a few more words, before it wrapped.

Comment: @vel look at the comment above, wrapping too early, too much margin left

Comment: That's the way text-wrapping works.

Comment: @Paulie_D I do want it to wrap if the window resizes beyond of what can be seen

Comment: You can't do that with `position:absolute` *unless you set a* **width**. You might want to try another layout/centering method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how text wrapping works. When you put the div to left 50% of the page, max width it can obtain is from that starting point at 50% left of screen to right edge of the page, i.e. 50% only. Which is you view is getting.

Thus when using translate for centering a div, you must specify the width if you want to fill it the parent.

So ,just specify the width for your element!

add this code:

```
div{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 90%;
}
```

change as per your need!

Comment: yes, that solves it, what's up with all the down-votes, people are really trying to discourage others from asking questions

Comment: @Yan even I was going to downvote it :), cause at first glance It's pretty hard to understand what you are asking! I understood it cause some time back I also faced the same problem. I think you should rephrase it :)